# Wagtail: Changing the default setting for "UserProfile.submitted_notifications" from "True" to "False"

Tags: django, wagtail

The default notification setting for a wagtail user instance seems to be "Receive notification when a page is submitted for moderation", which does not fit our needs: we do not want each and every wagtail user to be notified (emailed) when a page gets submitted for moderation.

The default for this user notification setting is "True":

```
# wagtail/wagtail/users/models.py
# https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/users/models.py#L25
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    submitted_notifications = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name=_('submitted notifications'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_("Receive notification when a page is submitted for moderation")
)
```

… and I would like to change the default to "False" (e.g. users should opt-in for getting email notifications).

But I do not know what’s the “best practices approach” for this task.

And I was a little surprised to have this problem at all, since I assumed that only members of the "Moderators" group/role would be notified. (which does not seem to be true).

---

What I tried/thought of:

- Modifying this setting pro grammatically (which worked):

  Existing user instances could be modified via shell:

  ```
  ./manage.py shell
  from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
  User = get_user_model()
  for user in User.objects.all():
      user.wagtail_userprofile.update(submitted_notifications=False)
      user.wagtail_userprofile.save()
  ```
- Modifying this setting in my CustomUser save() method (does *not* work):

  ```
  # project/users/models.py (pseudocode)
  class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
      def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super().save(*args, **kwargs)

          self.wagtail_userprofile.update(submitted_notifications=False)
          self.wagtail_userprofile.save()
  ```

  This raises a "RelatedObjectDoesNotExist" error.
- Adding a data migration to alter the default value (just an idea – I did not know if that’s an option or how to implement this).

---

Setup:

- django 2.0.8
- wagtail 2.2.2

Answer (score 1):

You can use a post save signal

```
import UserProfile from wagtail.users.models   

@receiver(post_save, sender=UserProfile)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
   if created:
       instance.submitted_notifications = False
       instance.save()
```

So this triggers when ever a new Profile is created and sets the 'submitted_notifications' default to False. Hope it helps

Comment: Dear Damilola, thanks, this would be the last option I consider, as I switched from some previously used signals to my custom model save() method... I would prefer changing the default setting.

Comment: Signals are not the same as save methods. They are fired on a different moment and therefore can serve a different purpose. Some might say that signals are magic and you should not use them. But moving your code from signals to save or vice versa is _not only_ a matter of style. The `post_save` signal does what is says. After save. Overriding save -like you do a this moment- is still too early.

Comment: Thanks @allcaps , I know, and  I really do not want to have this "default resetting" in my save method nor in a signal. I do not like to the idea to set this value on each an every new instance just because I can not change this unwanted initial default.  But if it is not possible to change the default value, I will set it via a signal.

Answer (score 0):

The reason updating the related profile in the save method raises a `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` is because related objects are created after save. The db transaction needs to commit to get a primary key. Obviously you need a pk to store the relation.

This is why signals work. The post save signal is fired after the db transaction is finished. I think a signal is a valid solution to your problem.

You can use `transaction.on_commit` in your save method too. On commit waits for the transaction to be finished.

Sometimes you need to perform an action related to the current database transaction, but only if the transaction successfully commits. Examples might include a Celery task, an email notification, cache invalidation or setting some default in a related object. This is the documentation on that topic:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/transactions/#performing-actions-after-commit

In your model do something like:

```
from django.db import transaction

class Foo(...):
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.pk:
            transaction.on_commit(self.update_profile)
        return instance

    def update_profile(self):
        self.wagtail_userprofile.update(submitted_notifications=False)
        # Note: update, no need to call save. 
        # Signals will not be fired on behalf of the UserProfile.
```

Disclaimer, I did not run/test this code.